# How can each element in Set be a Map.Entry object?

Tags: java

I am  a bit confused. i was reading the map interface. It has to use entrySet() method for collection view to use iterator. entrySet() return a Set that contains the elements of map. Again, each of this Set element is a Map.Entry object. how is that possible? as Set contains only one field, whereas Map.Entry is a key value pair?

Comment: A Set contains only one field? What do you mean by that. A Set is ... a set of elements. And each element of the set is a map entry. And each map entry has a key and a value. Sounds pretty logical to me.

Comment: It's not clear what the misunderstanding is here.  A `Set` contains (references to) objects, in this case the objects happen to be of type `Map.Entry`.

Comment: so , its something like- Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> sets  ?

Comment: Yes they are. It is just that their elements are of type `Map.Entry`. No mystery here ;)

Answer (score 6):

A map is basically a set of `key => value` mappings. In addition, the keys are unique and the values don't have to be. A key-value pair is encapsulated within a `Map.Entry` object. When you iterate over the entries of a map (= the set of key-value pairs), for each `entry` you can get the key with `entry.getKey()` and the value with `entry.getValue()`.

In addition to the set of entries, a map also provides the set of keys, and the collection of values. For example, in a `Map<String, Date>`, you have the set of key-value pairs as `Set<Map.Entry<String, Date>>`, the set of keys as `Set<String>` and the collection of values as `Collection<Date>`.

A concrete example of iterating over entries:

```
Map<String, Date> map = new HashMap<String, Date>();
map.put("now", new Date());
map.put("now+", new Date());
for (Map.Entry<String, Date> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Date value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println(String.format("%s => %s", key, value));
}
```

Another way to iterate is by keys:

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    Date value = map.get(key);
    System.out.println(String.format("%s => %s", key, value));
}
```

But this is less efficient because for each key you have to perform a lookup to get the value, in contrast with using entries with direct access to values.

Answer (score 4):

Set elements are objects, Map.Entry instance is also an object. All correct.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following: You can create your own `Cat` class with whichever properties you like. E.g.:

```
public class Cat {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private boolean isGrumpy;
    // etc...
}
```

As long as you implement `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()`, instances of this class can be put in a `Set`, right?

So why should `Map.Entry` be different? Just think of it as a class with two members - `key` and `value`.